# Firebase Javascript network error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase app and have started playing around with the [quickstart examples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js). I have created apps in Facebook, Google and Twitter and filled in the necessary clientId/secret information.

When testing the example pages facebook-credentials.html and google-credentials.html, everything works fine.

I am using Firebase 3.6.4 JS also.

When trying out the facebook-popup.html and facebook-redirect.html, and in fact the popup/redirect examples for Google and Twitter, I always get the following error in the Javascript console:

```
firebase.js:191 Uncaught Error: Network Error
at firebase.js:191
(anonymous) @ firebase.js:191
```

This seems to happen fairly quickly, but the HTTP request is still pending. After maybe 30 seconds, I then get another message in the console:

```
GET https://XXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=YYYYYYY&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&v=3.6.4&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.1grkUO4uZ2s.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMXwBvX3_duAb3Vw22ujByEbXKdJA net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

(note I have masked out my application name as XXXXXXX and API key as YYYYYYY).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I really want to get Twitter working, but there is no twitter-credentials method, so I'll need to get the popup or redirect working.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this was a lower level issue on my PC. I haven't gotten to the bottom of it yet but the Twitter examples work on another PC. At this point I am thinking it might be my antivirus or Firewall, so I am closing this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're also being blocked.  My application quit working, and another one that was using firebase also quit working, so we called IT.  There was new security software blocking the network request.  Similar errors, blank popup, that's how I ended up here.